# XHTML validation: element like not found

Tags: asp.net, xhtml

My aspx page has a few facebook plugins like, share, comment stream

```
<fb:like href="http://Thomasblog.somee.com" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font="lucida grande"></fb:like>
<p> Please add your comments and suuggestions </p>
<p><fb:comments href="http://Thomasblog.somee.com" num_posts="4" width="500"></fb:comments></p>
<p><a name="fb_share" type="Share" share_url="http://Thomasblog.somee.com"></p>
```

Here there is a error(Validation: XHTML 1.0) element like not supported. Same with comments and share

Here is my XHTML declaration

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head runat="server">
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook markup is not not valid XHTML (yet), so of course it won't validate. It's probably just a warning though, so you shouldn't have a problem with it assuming the markup is correct.